# Phar archive and stub file usage

Tags: php, deployment, stub, phar

I try to define a deployment procedure based on command :

```
php <phar_file_deployed_on_server>.phar
```

This command generates an index.php file external to phar archive.

The index.php file will act as a "thin" dispatcher to N-file.php inside the phar archive.

Example of generated index.php file :

```
<?

$requiredFile = "phar://<phar_file_deployed_on_server>.phar";

/**
 * For example index.php can check $_GET array and dispatch 
 * to file inside Phar archive.
 **/
if (array_key_exists("getParameter", $_GET))
    $requiredFile = $requiredFile . "/" . $_GET['getParameter'] . ".php";
else
    <handling_of_else_condition>;

require_once $requiredFile;

__HALT_COMPILER();

?>
```

**The above dispathing rule is an example.**

My idea is oriented to simply the deployment procedure. The example provided check $_GET array, but it's possible a more complex rule generated during deployment (e.g. via command line parameter).

> I have created a PHP web application and compressed it to the Phar
>   format for easy deployment.
>
> The application can be executed without decompression on a production
>   machine, because I have planned an `index.php` file that links to the
>   application inside the Phar archive.
>
> To generate the `index.php` file during deployment, it is necessary to
>   launch the following command into production machine shell:
>
> ```
> php <just_deployed_phar_file>
> ```
>
> The code inside the stub file generates the `index.php` file in manner
>   to refer to the just installed Phar archive.
>
> Is this the correct way to use the stub file?

Comment: You should at least show some of the code that is doing the work you describe others it's hard to say from your question.

Comment: You can get some informations about the stub here : http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.stub.php

You can basically do anything you want in the stub but the defaut stub starts the index.php

Your question is not clear enough at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stub file to do whatever you want to do. When the phar is executed (with php xxx.phar)
If I get your question right, you're planning to use your phar file as an installer for your whole application. It installs the index.php and then uses the phar to load your application. That would do its job, but there is a better way:

I think you're searching for [webPhar](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.webphar.php), which acts like a frontcontroller for your application. If you use webPhar() in the stub of your phar the request from your webserver is routed to your phar.